# JQuery Boilerplate plugin uses the same internal variables for new instance

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, boilerplate

I've created a simple JQuery plugin based on Boilerplate template. It works good except one problem. When I apply my plugin to the second `<div>`, the first one stops working. Moreover, all divs have the same unique id which I generate when creating new instance. How to restructure existing code to encapsulate variables and make it works correctly?
The code below is my plugin:

```
;(function($) {

    var pluginName = "Pulsar",
        dataKey = "plugin_" + pluginName,
        defaults = {
            key : "color",
            from: "#000",
            to: "#fff",         
            duration: 5         
        };

    var self = null;
    var interval = null;    
    var flag = false;
    var uniqueID = uniqueId();

    //PRIVATE FUNCTIONS
    function Plugin( element, options ) {
        this.element = element;
        this.options = $.extend( {}, defaults, options) ;
        this._defaults = defaults;
        this._name = pluginName;

        this.init();        
    }

    function uniqueId() {
      return 'id-' + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 16);
    };      

    function Init(key, from, to, duration){
        $(self.element).css({ 
            WebkitTransition : 'all ease '+duration+'s',
            MozTransition    : 'all ease '+duration+'s',
            MsTransition     : 'all ease '+duration+'s',
            OTransition      : 'all ease '+duration+'s',
            transition       : 'all ease '+duration+'s' 
        });
        $(self.element).text($(self.element).text()+' '+uniqueID);  

        var state1, state2; 

        state1 = '{ "'+key+'" : "'+from+'"}';
        state2 = '{ "'+key+'" : "'+to+'"}';

        var state1JSON = JSON.parse(state1);
        var state2JSON = JSON.parse(state2);

        $(self.element).css(state1JSON);

        clearInterval(interval);
        interval = setInterval(function(){
            if(!flag){
                $(self.element).css(state2JSON);
                flag=true;                  
            }
            else{
                $(self.element).css(state1JSON);
                flag=false;             
            }               
        }, duration * 1000);
    }

    //PUBLIC FUNCTIONS
    Plugin.prototype = {
        init: function(){
            self = this;
            $(self.element).attr("pluginID", uniqueID);         
            Init(this.options.key, this.options.from, this.options.to, this.options.duration);
        },
        update: function(key, from, to, duration){          
            Init(key, from, to, duration);          
        },
        getID: function(){
            return uniqueID;
        }
    };

    $.fn[pluginName] = function ( options ) {
        var plugin = this.data(dataKey);

        // has plugin instantiated ?
        if (plugin instanceof Plugin) {
            // if have options arguments, call plugin.init() again
            if (typeof options !== 'undefined') {
                plugin.init(options);
            }
        } else {
            plugin = new Plugin(this, options);
            this.data(dataKey, plugin);
        }

        return plugin;
    };


})(jQuery);
```

How it works you can see on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/haevd4ph/)

**UPDATE:**
My mistake was declaring variables in wrong place and their using, so they were used by all instances and not concrete instance. Thanks to guest271314. He gave me an idea how to correct my issue. The correct plugin which works like a charm is bellow:

```
;(function($) {

var pluginName = "Pulsar",
    dataKey = "plugin_" + pluginName,
    defaults = {
        key : "color",
        from: "#000",
        to: "#fff",         
        duration: 5,            
        onChange: function(){}
    };


//PRIVATE FUNCTIONS
function Plugin( element, options ) {
    this.element = element;
    this.options = $.extend( {}, defaults, options) ;
    this._defaults = defaults;
    this._name = pluginName;

    //init all required variables
    this.interval = null;
    this.flag = false;

    this.init(options);     
}

function Init(self, key, from, to, duration){
    var element = self.element;

    $(element).css({ 
        WebkitTransition : 'all '+duration+'s',
        MozTransition    : 'all '+duration+'s',
        MsTransition     : 'all '+duration+'s',
        OTransition      : 'all '+duration+'s',
        transition       : 'all '+duration+'s'  
    });     

    var state1, state2; 

    state1 = '{ "'+key+'" : "'+from+'"}';
    state2 = '{ "'+key+'" : "'+to+'"}';

    var state1JSON = JSON.parse(state1);
    var state2JSON = JSON.parse(state2);

    $(element).css(state1JSON);

    if(self.interval != null){          
        clearInterval(self.interval);
    } 
    self.interval = setInterval(function(){
        if(!self.flag){
            $(element).css(state2JSON);
            self.flag=true; 
            self.options.onChange();
        }
        else{
            $(element).css(state1JSON);
            self.flag=false;
            self.options.onChange();
        }               
    }, duration * 1000);
}

//PUBLIC FUNCTIONS
Plugin.prototype = {
    init: function(options){        
        var options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);      
        Init(this, options.key, options.from, options.to, options.duration);
    },
    update: function(key, from, to, duration){          
        Init(this, key, from, to, duration);            
    }
};

$.fn[pluginName] = function ( options ) {
     var plugin = this.data(dataKey);

    // has plugin instantiated ?
    if (plugin instanceof Plugin) {
        // if have options arguments, call plugin.init() again
        if (typeof options !== 'undefined') { 
            plugin.init(options);
        }
    } else {
        plugin = new Plugin(this, options);
        this.data(dataKey, plugin);
    }

    return plugin;
};
})(jQuery);
```

See how it works now - [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/haevd4ph/7/)

Comment: Try substituting `return this` for `return plugin` https://jsfiddle.net/haevd4ph/1/

Comment: @guest271314, did you see the result? It's the same as mine. The first div still doesn't work .

Comment: Not certain what expected rendered result is ? How should first `div` render ?  Also, to create unique id try calling `uniqueId()` at `$(self.element).attr("pluginID", uniqueId())` https://jsfiddle.net/haevd4ph/3/

Comment: @guest271314, it should continue blinking using its own parameters.

Comment: @guest27131, the behaviour have to be the same as if I create the same plugin and name it as `Pulsar2` and apply it to the second div. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/haevd4ph/4/)

Comment: Actually the "boilerplate" pattern is not entirely clear here. Will attempt to adjust to return expected results. Can create function at jsfiddle If were to call effects without plugin pattern on single element ?

Comment: @guest271314, actually, my goal is to get working plugin template which could be applied to every divs.

Comment: Yes. Though can create example where plugin pattern is not used ? For example, if goal was to apply effect to single div, without using `Plugin` function; using only `css` properties; that is, how would plugin function if it was not a plugin , with bare minimal. Also, may be helpful to add comments to `js` for viewers to interpret what intended processes are correctly

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28395652/jquery-plugin-update-settings-after-initialization/28397613#28397613

Comment: @guest271314, the code inside the plugin is just for example. If it's easier, you can change functionality of the plugin as you want. It applies css to div just to show that plugin works incorrectly if I apply it to another div. That's it. It seems to me that variables such as `self`, `uniqueID` are used in the same context. And it's a reason why it doesn't work.

Comment: See post, `clearInterval(interval)` may have been issue

Comment: Tried chaining a jQuery method to `.Pulsar()` at https://jsfiddle.net/haevd4ph/7/ ? Try substituting returning `this` for `plugin` at `$.fn[pluginName]` from https://jsfiddle.net/haevd4ph/8/

Comment: @guest271314, if I change `return plugin` to `return this`, I get chaining, but lose an ability to invoke internal functions such as `update`. I do it like `$('#pulsar').Pulsar({...}).update(...)`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/haevd4ph/9/

Comment: @guest271314, good, but a bit cumbersome and not obvious!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`clearInterval(interval)` being called before `interval = setInterval`  may have been issue; also try setting `flag` at `this.data()`

```js
;(function($) {

  var pluginName = "Pulsar",
    dataKey = "plugin_" + pluginName,
    defaults = {
      key: "color",
      from: "#000",
      to: "#fff",
      duration: 5
    };

  var interval = null;

  function uniqueId() {
    return 'id-' + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 16);
  };

  function Init(key, from, to, duration) {
    $(this).css({
      WebkitTransition: 'all ease ' + duration + 's',
      MozTransition: 'all ease ' + duration + 's',
      MsTransition: 'all ease ' + duration + 's',
      OTransition: 'all ease ' + duration + 's',
      transition: 'all ease ' + duration + 's'
    });
    $(this).text(uniqueId());

    var state1, state2;

    state1 = '{ "' + key + '" : "' + from + '"}';
    state2 = '{ "' + key + '" : "' + to + '"}';

    var state1JSON = JSON.parse(state1);
    var state2JSON = JSON.parse(state2);

    $(this).css(state1JSON);

    interval = setInterval(function() {
      if (!$(this).data().flag) {
        $(this).css(state2JSON);
        $(this).data().flag = true;
      } else {
        $(this).css(state1JSON);
        $(this).data().flag = false;
      }
    }.bind(this), duration * 1000);
    return this
  }

  $.fn[pluginName] = function(options) {
    this.data("flag", false);
    var options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
    return Init.call(this, options.key, options.from, options.to, options.duration);
  };

})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {

  //FOR SINGLE PROPERTY
  $("#pulsar").Pulsar({
    duration: 2,
    key: 'textShadow',
    from: '0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)',
    to: '0px 0px 30px rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)'
  });

  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#pulsar2").Pulsar({
      duration: 1,
      key: 'textShadow',
      from: '0px 0px 5px rgba(255, 0, 255, 1)',
      to: '0px 0px 30px rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)'
    });
  }, 5000);

});
```

```css
body,
html {
  background-color: #000;
}
.pulsar {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 57px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.pulsar2 {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 47px;
  top: 70%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="pulsar" class="pulsar">PULSAR</div>
<div id="pulsar2" class="pulsar2">PULSAR 2</div>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/haevd4ph/5/

Comment: @Nolesh Version setting `interval` at element `.data()` for `interval` to be cleared using `clearInterval($("#pulsar2").data().interval)` https://jsfiddle.net/haevd4ph/6/

Comment: Thanks, you gave me an idea! See my updated question.