# Jquery plugin change default value after init

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I created this simple plugin

```
;(function ($, window, document, undefined) {
    //Function-level strict mode syntax
    'use strict';

    /**
     * PLUGIN
     */
    $.fn.Plugin = function(options) {
        var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.Plugin.defaults, options);
        return this.each(function() {
            var that = this;
            console.log ("plugin init with " + opts.var + " - " + opts.act);
            if (opts.pre) {
                console.log ("preset enable");
            }
        });
    };

    $.fn.Plugin.defaults = {
        var: 'id',
        act: null,
        pre: false,
    };
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

I wish insert/modify a default value, after I initialized,
keeping the values I initialized at the start.

Like this

```
$('div').Plugin({ 
    var: 'foo', 
    act: 'go' 
});  //  plugin init with foo - go

$('.btn').on('click', function() {
    $('div').Plugin({ 
        pre: true 
    }); // plugin init with foo - go // preset enable
});
```

How can I change the code of my plugin to do this?
Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. I noticed a possible typo in your code anyway:

if (opts.preset) should be if(opts.pre), according to your object's structure

Comment: @kennasoft - It was my mistake, now I correct my code.

Comment: Does that solve your problem, or are you going to elaborate on your question, a little more?

Comment: @kennasoft - I'd like to modify the structure of my plugin (maybe using methods?) so you can set some parameters of the plugin after it is initialized by keeping the values used to initialize it. Like in my example. I hope this is more clear. Thanks

Comment: You can take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28396546/299708