# How to update options on a jQuery no-selector plugin after initialization?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wish to create a jQuery plugin with no selector but it takes some parameters that I could modify after initializing it.

On initialize its prototype like this:

```
var comment = $.comment({
                Enable: true,
                Area: 'body',
                maxComment: 5
            })
```

After that later on, if I want to update the option `maxComment` to 10, I want it to have a function of that to be like:

```
comment.setMaxComment(10)
```

Then as well to disable the plugin with method like this:

```
comment.Enable(false)
```

I have searched around for such an options but only found the tutorial of jQuery plugin with selector like `$.fn.PluginName` as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28395652/jquery-plugin-update-settings-after-initialization).

Apologize that I could not post a whole js code of my plugin, but I am looking for a prototype method that update the plugin options on the fly like this.

Comment: It's just an ordinary assignment: `$.comment = function ...`

Comment: @Barmar, thanks I know about initialize the plugin, but I could not re-intailize it with their updated options.

Comment: This would be easier to do using ES6 classes. If you still want to execute it using `$.comment` you could do `$.comment = options => new CommentClass(options);`

Comment: @Barmar, could you help me how can I set method setMaxComment that will update plugin option MaxComment, as well as Enable option then the plugin could re-initialized with these new updates ? Thanks very much.

Comment: Not that most JavaScript developers are going to expect properties and methods to start with a lowercase letter (`enable` vs `Enable`). [Addy Osmani wrote a guide on jQuery plugins](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/essential-jquery-plugin-patterns/) which is essential reading.

Comment: The plugin should return an object with a property like `setMaxComment: function(max) { this.maxComment = max; }`

Comment: @Barmar, it did not work, thanks

Comment: ```Cannot read property 'setMaxComment' of undefined```